# Confused about the following 'generics' code

Tags: java, generics

I can't seem to fully understand the following statement.

`<T> T[] toArray( T[] a );`

Although, I understand that the above statement is the declaration of a function that should be able to accept and return an array of `T` type objects... I do not understand why

1 - The two `T`'s are not surrounded with `<>`

2 - There appear to be 2 return types, as in `<T>` & `T[]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<T>` is not a return type. It's a declaration of the generic type parameter used by the method. Once it's declared, it can be used in the method signature without the `<>`;

Comment: And it's surrounded with `<>` because that's how its format was defined.

Comment: So would it be possible for me to write the same declaration without the first `<T>` and then simply surrounding the the other 2 `T`'s with `<>`? So for example can I declare the above with `<T>[] toArray( <T>[] a );` instead?

Comment: @Grateful No, that wouldn't be proper Java syntax. If that method was part of a class that declares the generic parameter T (`public class SomeClass<T>`), you could omit the `<T>` from the method declaration, but the other two T's would stay the same.

Comment: Oooooohh, I see! But I presume within that class definition I would still be required to use the angle brackets if talking about a collection of some kind. So although I could omit the brackets for something like `T[] toArray( T[] a );` I would still be required to have the brackets for `ListIterator<T> listIterator();`

Comment: @Grateful `ListIterator<T>` is a different use of `<>`. Here you are specifying the type of data the ListIterator will return. It can be any type (for example `ListIterator<String>`), not necessarily a generic type parameter that was previously declared.

Answer (score 1):

1. declares that the method is parameterised by T, as opposed to the containing class for example. The angled brackets are part of the syntax, not the variable name
2. As in 1,  is not a return type

Answer (score 0):

The return type is `T[]` and not `<T>`. What  indicates is that the method  is a generic type and implementations should take care of the type accordingly.

The two T's not surrounded by <> are the input parameter type and return type. In this case both should be same.